# XML XElement and loops

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Please help me to fix the piece of code that results in this xml output.

The elements called "Frequency" and "ScheduleType" are all being stuck under the first element of schedule. How do I fix this?

I'm reading data from a CSV type file and then based on the position and value I add the relevant data (or converted values) to the relevant XML values.

You'll see that I use the suggested method where possible but as I have to use an additional CASE statement I get stuck so I revert to using the LAST statement to try and find the correct element to continue from.

```
  <Schedules>
    <Schedule Number="1">
      <ScheduleName>Cumulative</ScheduleName>
      <BackupType>Cinc</BackupType>
      <Multiplexing>4</Multiplexing>
      <RetentionLevel>infinite</RetentionLevel>
      <ResidenceIsSLP>No</ResidenceIsSLP>
      <MultipleCopies>No</MultipleCopies>
      <ScheduleType />
      <Frequency>
        <Count>5</Count>
        <Unit>Days</Unit>
        <Count>2</Count>
        <Unit>Weeks</Unit>
        <Count>1</Count>
        <Unit>Days</Unit>
      </Frequency>
      <ScheduleType />
      <Frequency />
      <ScheduleType />
      <Frequency />
    </Schedule>
    <Schedule Number="2">
      <ScheduleName>Full</ScheduleName>
      <BackupType>Full</BackupType>
      <Multiplexing>4</Multiplexing>
      <RetentionLevel>infinite</RetentionLevel>
      <ResidenceIsSLP>No</ResidenceIsSLP>
      <MultipleCopies>No</MultipleCopies>
    </Schedule>
    <Schedule Number="3">
      <ScheduleName>Differential</ScheduleName>
      <BackupType>Diff</BackupType>
      <Multiplexing>4</Multiplexing>
      <RetentionLevel>2 weeks</RetentionLevel>
      <ResidenceIsSLP>No</ResidenceIsSLP>
      <MultipleCopies>No</MultipleCopies>
    </Schedule>
  </Schedules>

public XDocument PolicyAttributesSection()
{
    XDocument policies = XDocument.Load("C:\\Output Files\\testnbu.xml");

    policies.Element("NBUConfig").Add(new XElement("Policies"));
    using (TextFieldParser policy = new TextFieldParser("C:\\Input Files\\RAM\\bppllist.txt"))
    {
        string[] ignoreLines1 = { "NAMES", "KEY", "RCMD", "BCMD", "FOE", "SHAREGROUP", "APPLICATIONDEFINED", "SCHEDFOE" };
        policy.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
        policy.Delimiters = new string[] { " ", ",", ";" };
        policy.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
        policy.CommentTokens = ignoreLines1;
        policy.TrimWhiteSpace = true;

        string[] policyprops;
        int schedulenumber;

        while (!policy.EndOfData)
        {

             schedulenumber = 0;
            var pl = policies.Element("NBUConfig").Element("Policies").Elements("Policy");
            policyprops = policy.ReadFields();
            switch (policyprops[0])
            {
            case "SCHED":
                    schedulenumber++;
                    int scheduletypenumber;
                    bool schedparsed = int.TryParse((policyprops[2]), out scheduletypenumber);
                    string scheduletypename = ScheduleType_Lookup[(scheduletypenumber)];
                    int retlevel;
                    bool retparsed = int.TryParse((policyprops[5]), out retlevel);
                    string retentionperiod = (Retention_Lookup[(retlevel)]).ToString();
                    int isslp;
                    bool isslpparsed = int.TryParse((policyprops[17]), out isslp);
                    int copynumber;
                    bool copynumberparsed = int.TryParse((policyprops[12]), out copynumber);
                    if (copynumber > 0)
                    {
                        copynumber = 1;
                    }
                    pl.Last().Element("Schedules").Add(new XElement(("Schedule"), new XAttribute("Number", (schedulenumber)),
                    (new XElement("ScheduleName", policyprops[1])),
                    (new XElement("BackupType", (scheduletypename))),
                    (new XElement("Multiplexing", policyprops[3])),
                    (new XElement("RetentionLevel", (retentionperiod))),
                    (new XElement("ResidenceIsSLP", (yesno_lookup[(isslp)]))),
                    (new XElement("MultipleCopies", (yesno_lookup[(copynumber)])))));
                    pl.Last().Element("Schedules").Element("Schedule").Add(new XElement(("ScheduleType")));
                    switch (policyprops[11])
                    {
                        case "1":
                            pl.Last().Element("Schedules").Element("Schedule").Add(new XElement("Calendar", "Enabled"));
                            pl.Last().Element("Schedules").Element("Schedule").Add
                    (new XElement("CalendarRetries", "Disabled"));
                            break;
                        case "2":
                            pl.Last().Element("Schedules").Element("Schedule").Add
                    (new XElement("Calendar", "Enabled"));
                            pl.Last().Element("Schedules").Element("Schedule").Add
                    (new XElement("CalendarRetries", "Enabled"));
                            break;
                        case "0":
                            int freqseconds;
                            bool startparsed = int.TryParse((policyprops[4]), out freqseconds);
                            var freq = frequency(freqseconds);
                            pl.Last().Element("Schedules").Element("Schedule").Add
                    (new XElement("Frequency"));
                            int count = freq.Item1;
                            string unit = freq.Item2;
                            pl.Last().Element("Schedules").Element("Schedule").Element("Frequency").Add
                    (new XElement("Count", (count).ToString()));
                            pl.Last().Element("Schedules").Element("Schedule").Element("Frequency").Add
                    (new XElement("Unit", (unit)));
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        policies.Save("C:\\Output Files\\testnbu.xml");
        return policies;
```

Comment: First thing to do: make your code *much* simpler by declaring a variable holding a reference to the `Policies` element. Next, *inside* the loop, declare a variable referring to the `Policy` element you're adding. I would suggest you do that and modify your question, to make it much easier for everyone to help you.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm still learning. Appreciate your assistance. I'll do it and repost.

Comment: Even with the change, you're still using `pol.Last` 6 times... instead of holding a reference to the `Policy` element you're currently creating. You've also got typos in "Schudule" instead of "Schedule".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement is the problem:

```
test.Element("NBUConfig")
    .Element("Policies")
    .Elements("Policy").Last()
    .Elements("Schedules").Last()
    .Element("Schedule")
    .Add(new XElement(("SchedulesStuff"), (scount)));
```

You're adding the `SchedulesStuff` to the first `Schedule` element within the last `Schedules` element... instead of adding it to the *last* `Schedule` element within the *only* `Schedules` element.

All of this code would be much, much simpler - and less error-prone - if you had far less repetitive code. So consider instead:

```
var policies = new XElement("Policies");
var test = new XDocument(new XElement("NBUConfig", policies));

// Hint: for loops are more idiomatic than while loops here
for (int pcount = 0; pcount < 3; pcount++)
{
    var schedules = new XElement("Schedules");
    for (int scount = 0; scount < 3; scount++)
    {
        schedules.Add(new XElement("Schedule",
            new XAttribute("Number", scount),
            new XElement("ScheduleStuff", scount));
    }

    policies.Add(new XElement("Policy",
        new XElement("PolicyName", pcount),
        new XElement("General"),
        new XElement("Clients"),
        new XElement("IncludeList"),
        schedules));        
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. The reason I'm using such a long method is because I have to read and manipulate the data from input file, and add more elements before proceeding to the next major sections such as General, Clients, IncludeLists, etc. I'm probably doing this in an idiotic way but I've got 1 month's experience. As I said this is not the real code I just used the while loop to simulate. I'll cleanup as per your previous recommendation and then post a bit of it. Maybe that will clarify the issue.

Comment: @RiaanBadenhorst: Well no, there's no need to do that on *this* question, because it's not really related to the question. But the general principle of avoiding all those `Element()` calls still applies. You could create the `General` element separately, then the `Clients` element etc, and still use local variables to refer to those elements, just as I have with `schedules`.

Comment: Hi Jon, ok I think i tried something similar to that earlier today. The only thing I noticed was when I used the .Add that i creates a completely new element, it doesn't just add another instance of Schedules for instance. Anyway to insert instead of Add?

Comment: @RiaanBadenhorst: I don't know what you mean by that, but I suggest you ask a new question with *just* that issue (with a [mcve] demonstrating it). Please focus on one issue per post - questions which move from one issue to another really don't work well on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sure no problem. I'll first try the add method some more. Thanks for the help.